# How to create a shared calendar that can be managed in iCal/iOS

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, google-workspace, outlook-web-access, office365

I have accounts on Google Apps and Office 365.

I'd like to share a calendar with other people and allow them to make changes (add/edit/delete events) within iCal or iOS.

I don't care whether I use Google Apps or Office 365, whichever is easiest. So far I've been able to grant "change" permissions to a shared calendar in Google Apps but then am unsure how I should add this within iCal. If I add a new calendar subscription I can see the shared calendar but can't add events to it.

In Office 365 I can share a calendar but can't change sharing permissions (in OWA the permissions panel just hangs).

Answer (score 0):

I not sure how you many do this without another account with the same provider (Google or Microsoft).

Through ICAL, you would not have ability to authenticate who can or cannot edit your calendar. Therefore, without the ability to login, the only permissions is "view".

This is to protect your data from random tampering.